# Cannot navigate to another controller after video is saved

Tags: ios, swift, view, uinavigationcontroller

First I save a video

```
 // MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

    extension RecVidController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(url.path, self, #selector(video(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

Then it comes here when finished saving....at which point I would like to navigate to another controller...

```
    @objc func video(_ videoPath: String, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo info: AnyObject) {

            let dwc = WordViewController(nibName:"WordViewController",bundle:nil)
            dwc.theString = "test"
            navigationController!.pushViewController(dwc, animated: true)


}
```

However...

```
class WordViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var txtWordDef: UITextField!
var theString:String!
```

All my interface variables like txtWordDef are nil....when I navigate to it....I've isolated all these classes as standalone views so I know the workflow can work. What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: removing "weak" (from IBOutlet) might work for you as sometime it work for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to declare variable `theString` in Class `WordViewController`

Comment: no its there...i would get a compile error otherwise